# MySQL multiple rows, grouping multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I really tried to do this by myself but seems that there is too complex query for a newbie like me.

on dgpl_se_bets1x2 table i have values for:

```
id, id_mat, prev, note, datetime
```

what is important of these:

id_mat = match id

prev = bet placed by user, values are 1, x or 2.

I want to print statistics about made bets, here is few lines for example:

```
+--+------+----+----+-------------------+
|id|id_mat|prev|note|datetime           |
+--+------+----+----+-------------------+
|6 |442   |2   |1   |2014-01-03 11:04:08|
+--+------+----+----+-------------------+
|5 |442   |1   |1   |2014-01-03 11:04:08|
+--+------+----+----+-------------------+
|5 |449   |1   |1   |2014-01-02 16:40:28|
+--+------+----+----+-------------------+
|6 |449   |1   |0   |2014-01-02 16:40:28|
+--+------+----+----+-------------------+
|7 |442   |2   |0   |2014-01-03 11:04:08|
+--+------+----+----+-------------------+
|8 |442   |2   |1   |2014-01-03 11:04:08|
+--+------+----+----+-------------------+
|7 |636   |2   |0   |2014-01-03 15:46:34|
+--+------+----+----+-------------------+
```

So there are matches 5,6,7 and 8.
And from that data I want to print out something like this:

```
+------------+-+-+-+
|Match Number|1|x|2|
+------------+-+-+-+
|5           |2|0|0|
+------------+-+-+-+
|6           |1|0|1|
+------------+-+-+-+
|7           |0|0|2|
+------------+-+-+-+
|8           |0|0|1|
+------------+-+-+-+
```

Or even better, with percentages:

```
+------------+---+-+---+
|Match Number|1  |x|2  |
+------------+---+-+---+
|5           |100|0|0  |
+------------+---+-+---+
|6           |50 |0|50 |
+------------+---+-+---+
|7           |0  |0|100|
+------------+---+-+---+
|8           |0  |0|100|
+------------+---+-+---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
SELECT id_mat,
    (SUM(prev='1')/COUNT(*))*100 AS prev1,
    (SUM(prev='x')/COUNT(*))*100 AS prevX,
    (SUM(prev='2')/COUNT(*))*100 AS prev2
FROM dgpl_se_bets1x2
GROUP BY id_mat;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Wasnt so hard that I thought it would be. Thank you very much Patrick :)